QGIS Server available only on port :8001
I installed QGIS Server on Windows and Windows Server (x64) following the official guide - https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows
Changing Listen ${SRVPORT} in httpd.conf file to port 80 or 8080 does not work.
QGIS Server is up and running only on port 8001 by default even if I don't change anything in the httpd.conf file.
For port 80 I get the standard error "Hmmm... can't reach this page", while for port 8080:
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
I reviewed and tried all possible solutions from the Internet - nothing helped.
